# React redux persist: mix local and AsyncStorage

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

Is it possible to use local storage with redux-persist but save it to AsyncStorage but only when app is closed/goes to background? So the state is not saved to storage on every action.

Comment: or any other option to disable automatic persist?